# Lucene Javadoc package

Tags: java, lucene, package, javadoc

Does Lucene has separated jar with javadoc inside ? Everything in contrib section has separated javadoc jars but it look to me that core has none. Am I right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it comes without jar for core javadocs. However you can easily make it by running "jar" utility from JDK on "/docs/api/core" folder from lucene-core-*.jar .